# No Data via Cellular iOS 10.2

Tags: iphone, cellular-data

I did a All Setting Reset and after the reset the data via cellular is not working ( 3G & LTE not showing in the status bar ) only via wireless , tried to reboot the device ,reset network setting but still not working ....

Any Solution from your side ? Note i don't want to update my iOS

Comment: Did you contact your cellular provider about this? Could be a problem with your SIM card or your subscription.

Comment: i put my sim card in another phone and its working fine

Comment: You shouldn’t have to update the settings for 10.2 but only your carrier can dig into why the good SIM isn’t connecting on the device you want it to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Like all data issues, your best bet is to contact the carrier. They have access to your account, the cell tower logs and diagnostics and can resolve service issues most rapidly.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201415

Steps to fix service issues in rural American is generally different then in the city in the United States. As is Europe and Asia and around the world, each region and each carrier has different ways and levels of serviceto troubleshoot and help you.